# Retroprophetic mondegreens

Tags: knowledge, music

In the misheard lyrics below, after finding out about the relative chronology, I found myself briefly wondering how the song authors knew what they were singing about years ahead of time.  Then, I found out I was just mistaken about what they were singing.

> 1. Elton John singing about a certain actor, 6 years before that actor's major TV debut.
> 2. Blondie singing about audio technology, 16 years before its name was coined.
> 3. Def Leppard singing about a popular gadget, 20 years before its initial release.

In each case, can you identify the original song and lyrics, along with the misheard version of the lyrics?

---

Hints for 2:

> The misheard lyrics are rather "compressed" compared to the actual lyrics.

> A ripping good time on one side, and a fragile emotional state on the other side?

> The misheard lyrics are two letters and a number; while the actual lyrics are two prepositions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Elton John singing about a certain actor, 6 years before that actor's major TV debut.

> Song: [Tiny Dancer](https://youtu.be/yYcyacLRPNs?t=180)
>  Misheard lyrics: Hold me closer Tony Danza
>  Actual lyrics: Hold me closer tiny dancer

2. Blondie singing about audio technology, 16 years before its name was coined.

> I don't know. The audio technology could possibly be auto-tune.

3. Def Leppard singing about a popular gadget, 20 years before its initial release.

> Song: [Pour Some Sugar on Me](https://youtu.be/xU7yLn5DYQM?t=42)
>  Misheard lyrics: Living with a lover with a red IPhone
>  Actual lyrics: Living with a lover with a radar phone

Comment: 1 and 3 are correct; guess on 2 is not.

Comment: Given the latest hints, I think #2 might be [ROT13: gur ylevpf "va orgjrra" sebz Urneg bs Tbyq, zvfurneq nf "zc3"](http://decode.org/?q=gur+ylevpf+%22va+orgjrra%22+sebz+Urneg+bs+Tbyq%2C+zvfurneq+nf+%22zc3%22)

Comment: @ManyPinkHats Why not post that as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

2. "Blondie singing about audio technology, 16 years before its name was coined" is

   > Song: [Heart of Glass](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gbnbMMCfyoc)
   >  Misheard lyrics: mp3
   >  Actual lyrics: In between (around 59 seconds into the video linked)

Comment: That's correct.